# how to use Text view of one activity to display from a another pop up screen

Tags: android

I have an activity which have an text view in it , and i made an pop up screen and want to show on button click (i.e if i click on sin it will show sin)it will show that on my activity  text view

Comment: Write your question in proper way.

Comment: I recommend you read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unclear question & post properly with some code

Answer (score 0):

Use onClickListener for your button like this:

```
sinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        textViewName.setText(sinBtn.getText().toString().trim());

        }
});
```